# Can a biological gun be evolved or exist

Tags: biology, weapons, natural

I had an idea of a flying alien creature on a low gravity planet that would hunt in a unique way.

**It would evolve a biological gun on its forehead.**

Is such a thing plausible? If not, why?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Your question is answered by the answer given in the referred post citing the squirting cucumber.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. The other question is about exploding fruots. I have an answer for this one.

Comment: Check out the Bombardier Beetle.  It's butt is basically a steam cannon.  Or something like a  slingshot/bow, only with that weird stuff fleas and mantis shrimp use to store energy and release it all real fast.  A mantis shrimp's punch accelerates as fast as a .22 round in the barrel, WHILE UNDERWATER.  Take that and throw in some porcupine quills, and you've got an animal that can shoot its spines and has plenty to shoot.

Comment: IMHO, this is no more far-fetched than Larry Niven's Stage Trees. See the story, "A Relic of the Empire" URL discussing it here: https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/A_Relic_of_the_Empire

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw See new post:https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246477/how-might-this-creature-evolve-a-biological-gun. I'm voting to reopen this one as "nowhere near a duplicate of the other".

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. I think its hard for anyone to care very much about a 3 year old 3 line question with zero score and zero answers.

Comment: Wow, that long, doesn't time fly when you're having covid :) . Well see. @StarfishPrime

Comment: "Biological gun" could cover a lot of ground, as shown in some previous comments. I'm not sure this is specific enough to be answerable - it would help if the OP was more clear what their goal is, but if they're not active that probably won't happen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_use_by_non-human_organisms

Comment: On its forehead? Recoil would be a pretty serious issue, unless the projectiles were very low energy and/or the creature were very massive.

Comment: @pygosceles, No worse than the impact on the beak of a woodpecker. Lots of evolutionary reinforcement, sure, but not insurmountable.

Comment: You may want to look at the pistol shrimp and its 'plasma-gun' claw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpheidae#Snapping_effect

Answer (score 3):

## Nature has already done it

[image: termite with fontanellar gun]

This is a nasute termite, which bears a [fontanellar gun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontanellar_gun) on its forehead. This is a highly derived structure which fires a 'bullet' of sticky substance which immobilises attackers. While this structure specifically is for defense, many creatures (e.g. velvet worms or spitting spiders) which use sticky projectiles to hunt

Comment: Doesn't seem much different than spitting. Now that I think about it, there's plenty of spitting animals.