# Feasibility of Battlefield Grown Biological Weaponry

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, xenobiology

In a worldbuilding project I am working on, its main focus is around a zerg-like hivemind species hell bent on devouring biomass, while also having the ability to weave their genomes to form specialized bioforms to suit their needs. They utilize a variety of biological technology like living guns, specialized bioforms acting as tanks, etc. This hivemind utilizes swarm tactics, relying on sheer numbers to dominate the battlefield.

I had an idea of specialized plants that grow living guns for the footsoldiers of the swarm. It would utilize Hydrogen peroxide inside a separate chamber (With proper protection of course), I chose this chemical because it's a component of fuel used by rockets which could act as gunpowder substitute means of propulsion for its different ammunition., and it can be produced by living beings, example: Bombardier beetle.

With the gunpowder issue solved, all I'm struggling to think of right now is for it's design. What would it look like? Would it mimic the looks of modern weaponry despite it's biological origins?

How would it compare to an assault rifle like the AK-47, if the ammunition used is of the same caliber?

And lastly, the plants are designed for mass production + on the go, an unarmed footsoldier would just run and grab a newly grown weapon from the plant, and will grow another one for the next soldier. How long would this process of growing the weapon and ammunition take, if the energy needs are met, and the genome of the plant is supplied with enough instructions and information to form such a weapon?

Example Art:
[image: Look how fleshy it is]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  As this is a question-and-answer site, you need to confine your post to a single question, and you have many here.  If you want to ask many questions, you can split them into separate posts!  (I will say that if you've got the science-based tag up, this all sounds pretty unlikely.  Growth speeds - days or weeks - seem like they would be the biggest barrier.)

Comment: The Tyrannids and the Inquisition would like to know your location.

Comment: Also - I believe I've already answered this question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246477/how-might-this-creature-evolve-a-biological-gun/246486#246486

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How might this creature evolve a biological gun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246477/how-might-this-creature-evolve-a-biological-gun)

Comment: Hi @ArcticSad. (a) This site allows only one question per post. We're usually lenient with new users, but there's enough wrong with this Q to justify its closure to give you time to reason what you really need to ask. (b) When you see that comment from the automated Community BOT, it means your question has failed Stack Exchange's automatic heuristic check for a "good question." It means you really need to [edit] your question. (c) "Feasibility" is a loaded word here. We help people build imaginary worlds, in which everything is always feasible... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... (d) The design or look-and-feel of any object is an off-topic question here. Remember that Stack Exchange expects questions that are reasonably objective. Look-and-feel is never reasonably objective. We close such questions regularly. (e) Comparisons to Real World weapons are entirely up to you. Your weapon can be more or less powerful as you desire. It's not our place to judge since that's an issue of the story, not a rule of the world. Finally, (f) the process will take as long as you wish. This is due to ... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609), which means it will take as long as your story requires for the purposes of your story. Obviously, there isn't enough science behind your idea to objectively judge how long it takes... unless you mean strict science, in which case what you're proposing is scientifically impossible (which is why we focus on imaginary worlds). Oh, finally, finally, (g) if you read the tag wikis for [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction], you'll find they're mutually exclusive. I deleted the one that doesn't make sense.

Comment: One last thing: this is a cool idea. Don't discard it simply because it hasn't enough scientific basis. That's boring anyway. Science Fiction embraces the idea of "what if?" Otherwise the *Starcraft* games and *Starship Troopers* stories and film franchise wouldn't have been as popular as they were and are.

Comment: I seconding the JBH comments .. that aside, if you want a plausible benchmark figure for growth speed you could do worse than to take bamboo growth rates as a starting point, [Madake and Moso](https://myplantin.com/blog/how-fast-does-bamboo-grow#:~:text=What%20Is%20the%20Fastest%20Growing,14%20inches%20(35%20cm).) can grow an inch per hour and max out at 150 feet tall with a stem diameter of 14 inches that info lets you figure the volume grown per hour, just design your weapon, figure it's volume from its shape and size and use the bamboo growth rate to figure how long that may take.

Comment: If you want the grown material to have more density than bamboo adjust your math to reflect that, more density in the same volume means more mass and a plant will presumably take proportionately longer to grow the same volume of a denser material than bamboo grows.